# How to not pass empty input fields in HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, filter

I have a form that has about a hundred input/text fields for each of our companies products. The form is to be filled out at the end of the day with the number of each product that was sold.

How do I have the form only pass on the relatively small subset of fields that are NOT empty?

I'm not looking for form validation. It's ok for the user to either enter or not enter a value in any of the input fields; however I only want the input fields that did have a value entered into them to be included in the POST that the form passes along.

Thanks

Comment: can you share what you have started?

Comment: you are using .serializearray() or simple jquery to get all values ? if you use  .serializearray() then i have one solution.

Comment: I found this answer in a similar question to be most useful (setting disable works but is visually confusing, removing the name property has the same effect but doesn't change the way the page looks) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31376217/how-to-not-pass-empty-input-fields-in-html-form/31376894#31376894

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is to set all empty fields to disabled before submit, e.g.

```
function disableEmptyInputs(form) {
  var controls = form.elements;
  for (var i=0, iLen=controls.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    controls[i].disabled = controls[i].value == '';
  }
}
```

And run it on the form's submit listener:

```
<form onsubmit="disableEmptyInputs(this)" ...>
```

So any input that has a value of "" (empty string) will have its *disabled* property set to *true* and it won't be submitted.

Or to add the listener dynamically:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('formID').addEventListener('submit', function() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.elements, function(el) {
      el.disabled = el.value == '';
    });
  }, false);
};
```

Comment: I know this is a very old answer, but to anyone seeing this still, this answer will mean that controls become enabled if they have a non-empty value, **even if they were previously disabled for another reason.** This isn't always what you want, but can easily be adapted by arranging the for-loop body to be `if (controls[i].value == '') controls[i].disabled = true`.

Comment: It breaks the form when clicking the back button on Firefox v77.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did using JQuery:

```
$("#myform").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var dataArr = {};

    $.each($("form > input[name]"), function (key, value) {
        if ($(this).val() != "") {
            dataArr[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
        }
    });

    $.post($(this).attr('action'), dataArr);
    alert("Form submitted!");

});
```

What the above code does:

- Stops the default form submission
- Finds all the input fields that have a data
- Builds an array of the *valid* data
- Submits the form to the page defined by the *action* attribute of the form via the *POST* method
- Displays a message of the form submission.

[Here is the **JSFiddle** of the code](https://jsfiddle.net/8hxym5je/)

Comment: +1 for overriding the default POST behavior instead of disabling the UI fields, which may generate visual noise perceptible to the user

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have on a site for exactly this:

```
$("#my-form").submit(function() {
    $(this).find(":input").filter(function () {
        return !this.value;
    }).attr("disabled", true);

    return true;
});
```

It will disable all input fields in your form that doesn't have any value, which makes them not being sent in the request.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using JQuery

HTML

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input name="1" type="text" / >
    <input name="2" type="text" / >
    <input name="3" type="text" / >
    <input name="4" type="text" / >
    <button id="sub">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
(function(){    
    $('#sub').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $('form input').filter(function(index,ele){
        return $(ele).val()!= '';
    }).serialize();
    console.log(data)
 })
})()
```

Comment: It's usually considered very poor form to submit an answer that requires a library that isn't noted in the tag or asked for in the question and you haven't said is required (there are many libraries that use a "$" function). Especially when a non–library solution is very simple and much more efficient.